# Apache, permission denied accessing the web app folder after upgrading OSX to 10.9.2

Tags: macos, apache2

My Apache used to work fine, but I assume that problems came after upgrading OSX to 10.9.2, (anyway not certain about when the problem came) Apache was not working with the current configuration.

I tried `apachectl configtest` so I found out that the Apache's file structure on my machine was changed, from *Library/WebServer/Documents/* to *Library/WebServer/Apache Home* so I edited the `DocumentRoot` of *httpd.conf* to point to the new folder.

But the problem I still cannot fix is about the permission. I got **403 Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server.**

#### Extra Information

I hosted all my web projects at */Users/myname/home_www* this folder and it's sub folders belong to *_www* group, and has *775* access permission. I created a symlink at *Library/WebServer/Apache Home* (all these setup used to work fine)

I noticed some strange thing that the *Library/WebServer/* and its sub folders belong to *wheel* group, I never paid attention to these folders before that what group they belong to.

OSX: 10.9.2
Apache: 2.2.26

Comment: any message in `httpd-error` log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my case all problems seem to come after upgrading to 10.9.2, these are steps I have done to solve my problems.

1. Edit `DocumentRoot` to `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Apache Home"`
2. Edit `<Directory>` to `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Apache Home">`
3. This step may not be necessary but just in case, `brew upgrade`
4. Chenge owner and group of */usr/local/var/mysql/* to **mysql* using `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/`, otherwise `mysql.server start` will fail